# Globalization folder in lowercase

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

We upgraded from Xamarin Forms 3.x to 4.x version. Specific culture settings stopped working. Upon investigation found out that, for specific culture Xamarin creates the folder in lowercase compared to uppercase, so when we try to access the resource file it is not found. For example, "en-us", rather that "en-US". For info, Droid project generates it in the appropriate case.

Comment: Am sorry.. these folders created as part of build process and .ipa files and .apk files gets created with these folders... I think you are not right about Droid, i think the naming of culture is universal and for all cultures it does it rite and only for iOS "pt-BR" it isi generating wrongly. Filed a bug with MS

Comment: check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/12574/the-project-has-resource-resource-folders-using-uppercase-letters

Comment: no offense.. our app stopped working in iOS only for specific culture..again it doesn't explain why for other cultures it creates fine and only for portuguese brazil when we upgrade from FOrms 3.6 to 4.0

Comment: You can add a new issue thread on git and post the issue link here ,we will focus on it .

Comment: Thanks so much.. created 3 days before.. here is the link..https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6717